# How to sort various data types in one column in NatTables

Tags: java, nattable

I do have all values in Nattable as strings. I used `IConfigLabelAccumulator` and added labels `DataTypeStringLabel = "String"` and `DataTypeNumberLabel = "Number"` to cells. **In one column can be values with both types of labels**:

```
  public BodyLayerStack(List<TableLine> values, int columnCount, Integer[] columnIndicesForRowHeaders)
  {
    EventList<TableLine> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(values);
    TransformedList<TableLine, TableLine> rowObjectsGlazedList = GlazedLists.threadSafeList(eventList);

    // this.filterList = new FilterList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList); //changed to:
    // use the SortedList constructor with 'null' for the Comparator
    // because the Comparator will be set by configuration
    sortedList = new SortedList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList, null);
    // wrap the SortedList with the FilterList
    filterList = new FilterList<>(sortedList);
    
    bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<TableLine>(filterList, getColumnAccessor(columnCount));
    bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);

    IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
      
      @Override
      public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
        int columnIndex = bodyDataLayer.getColumnIndexByPosition(columnPosition);
        int rowIndex = bodyDataLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);
        if( isRowHeader(columnIndicesForRowHeaders, columnIndex) ) {
          configLabels.addLabel(NatTableFactory.RowHeaderLabel);
        } else {
          // get dataTypes at actual positions and add/refresh labels 
          configLabels.addLabel(filterList.get(rowIndex).getObjectTypeByColumn(columnIndex));
          if(configLabels.getLabels().get(0) != null && configLabels.getLabels().get(0)=="Number") {
            System.out.println("Number");                
          }
        }
      }
    };
    bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
    
    GlazedListsEventLayer<TableLine> glazedListsEventLayer = new GlazedListsEventLayer<>(bodyDataLayer, filterList);
    
    selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(glazedListsEventLayer, false);
    selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(getSelectionModel());
    selectionLayer.addConfiguration(getSelectionConfiguration());
    
    setUnderlyingLayer(new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer));
  }
```

For now, all values are sorted as strings (as expected). But I need to sort values with label `Number` as numbers.

What would be better: convert data to numbers, or use custom comparator?

- If I use data conversion, data are converted only for sort purpose? I need to keep data as Strings after sorting.
- If I use custom comparator, I am not sure, how to register Labels. Should I use already created `IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator`?

I was trying:

```
  public static IConfiguration getCustomComparatorConfiguration(final AbstractLayer columnHeaderDataLayer) {
    return new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {

      @Override
      public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
        
        // Register labels
        BodyLayerStack.super.getConfigLabelAccumulator().registerOverride( //ERROR
            4, //here should come index of sorted column?
                NatTableFactory.DataTypeNumberLabel);

        // Register custom comparator
        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                SortConfigAttributes.SORT_COMPARATOR,
                NatTableLayerConfigurations.getCustomComparator(),
                DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                NatTableFactory.DataTypeNumberLabel);
      }
    };
  }
```

but I get `The method registerOverride(int, String) is undefined for the type IConfigLabelAccumulator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an `IConfigLabelAccumulator` which does not provide the `registerOverride(int, String)` method. Not sure which subclass defines that method. The `ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator` provides the method `registerColumnOverride(int, String)`

I would suggest to use a custom `Comparator` if the sorting based on String representations is not sufficient.

https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=sorting

Comment: Hi @Dirk, I tried `registerColumnOverrides(int, String)` as well, but with the same error: `The method registerColumnOverrides(int, String) is undefined for the type IConfigLabelAccumulator`. My import seems to be fine:  `import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.cell.ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator;`. According to [manual](https://download.eclipse.org/nattable/releases/1.0.0/apidocs/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/layer/cell/class-use/IConfigLabelAccumulator.html) it should work. So I have no idea what did I miss.

Comment: The method `getConfigLabelAccumulator()` returns an `IConfigLabelAccumulator`. So you need to cast that to `ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator` to make use of the register method.

Comment: Hi @Dirk, one more question: is there a way, how to read cell labels in custom comparator? I created `public static Comparator<String> getCustomComparator()` , then I registered it for all columns: `labelAccumulator.registerOverrides(CUSTOM_COMPARATOR_LABEL);` In my comparator I get only two parameters: `String o1` and `String o2`. I would like to read if any of cell has "Number" label. If so, I would convert it to double and compare. Or am I thinking completely wrong? Thank you

Comment: The Comparator does not know about cells. So no IMHO there is no way to get that information